# How to modify the minimum word length in MySQL for just one table?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I know how to modify the [global configuration](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-full-text-index-word-length/) for MySQL on a server so that the minimum word length can be shorter than the default of 4 (unfortunately, our content contains a bunch of TLAs that need to be searchable).

However, I was wondering if I could use this more finely and only modify the one table that actually requires it.

Comment: This may not be the answer you were hoping for but the full text settings are server settings and can not be adjusted for different tables. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html